# Custom notification overlay - implement swipe down to reveal couple of buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I want to implement a custom notification over to be shown from with in my app. It should show a message and allow user to swipe down to reveal couple of buttons for action. I am supporting minimum iOS 6.

By far, I am able to create a custom view subclassing `UIView` and put up message in it. How do I implement the feature of swipe down to reveal couple of buttons?

Any references would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHandler:)];
    [gestureRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

    -(void)swipeHandler:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
        NSLog(@"Swipe received.");
    }
```

Comment: Adding a Swipe gesture is not a problem. I wanted to check how would I handle the view expansion and displaying additional buttons the way notifications are shown in iOS 10.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `UIView` below your notifications that will have a height of 0 and on swipe down, increase the height of that particular constraint.